# VBA: Get List Of Data From Another Column and Transfer them to another Column using loop

Tags: vba, excel

suppose I want to get a list of data and only want to get a certain string on each of every list and I want to transfer them to a different column.

For example I want to get a certain strings on every data in Column A, and I want to transfer those certain string to another column which is Column E. What I got so far is this, but its not working. Im fairly new to VBA and I hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

PS: What I mean for certain string is using mid function on every strings on that column.

```
Sub test()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRowE = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each MyCell In Range("E2:E" & LastRowE)

    MyCell.Value = Mid(Range("A2:A6"), 7, 2)

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go ahead and try the code below. You may adapt the code to your situation.

**Data before**

```
   A           B    C    D    E
1  hello 19
2  hello 20
3  hello 40
4  hello rr
```

**Code**

```
Sub test()

    ' find the last row assuming data starts from A1
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ' loop through E1..E<n>
    ' take value of corresponding row of column A and
    ' do MID on it. Put the result in A's row
    Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each MyCell In Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
        MyCell.Value = Mid(Range("A" & MyCell.Row), 7, 2)
    Next

End Sub
```

**After running the code**

```
   A           B    C    D    E
1  hello 19                   19
2  hello 20                   20
3  hello 40                   40
4  hello rr                   rr
```

Hope this information helps.